# 'I produce and rebuild' or 'I refurbish and fabricate'?

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms

Which sentence is better?

1. In my present job, **I produce and rebuild** machine parts used in
   the food sector.
2. In my present job, **I refurbish and fabricate** machinery parts for
   food industry.

Comment: What is meant by *rebuild* here? Restoration of areas worn down by friction?

Comment: What is meant by rebuild here? refurbish machinery parts

Comment: I guess you should describe in a separate question how exactly the parts are refurbished, so that others may suggest a proper term.

Answer (score 2):

I found these definitions:

> [**produce**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/produce_1) : create, make (to make, write etc something to be bought, used, or enjoyed by people)
>   [**fabricate**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fabricate) : to make or produce goods or equipment [= manufacture)
>   [**refurbish**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/refurbish) : to decorate and repair something such as a building or office in order to improve its appearance [↪ renovate]
>   [**rebuild**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rebuild): to make something strong and successful again or to build something again, after it has been damaged or destroyed.

From these definitions, I would choose *produce* and *rebuild* as I think they describe best what you do.